# Reducing the length of HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have the following HTML code -

```
<h4>Japan:</h4>
     <table width=100>
        <col width="30%">
        <col width="10%">
        <tr>
           <td>Value1:</td>
           <td align="right">200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value2:</td>
           <td align="right">500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value3:</td>
           <td align="right">33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value4:</td>
           <td align="right">11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value5:</td>
           <td align="right">123</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <h4>China:</h4>
              <table width=100>
        <col width="30%">
        <col width="10%">
        <tr>
           <td>Value1:</td>
           <td align="right">600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value2:</td>
           <td align="right">1100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value3:</td>
           <td align="right">444</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value4:</td>
           <td align="right">1112</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value5:</td>
           <td align="right">123321</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

The above code works fine and generates an HTML page. But the issue is with the repetition of some of the tags such as -

```
<table width=100>
            <col width="30%">
            <col width="10%">
```

and

```
align="right"
```

I wanted to know if there is anyway to reduce the code by adding these repetitive lines as a class or template.

The code contains only HTML file and no CSS or JS files (I can consider adding these files, if it helps in solving my problem).

Pardon me if this question sounds too trivial for HTML - as I'm new to the language.

Cheers!

Comment: you want to look into a server-side language like PHP. With PHP you can create templates and include them with a call, thus, no repetition and smaller code base :) http://php.net

Comment: That's kinda the point of template languages. There are plenty out there to choose from. I'm fond of template-toolkit.

Comment: If you add a css class and use that

Comment: Where did you learn to use those `align` properties? They were declared deprecated in the previous century and should not be taught to new HTML learners today.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can (and you should) do this with some CSS. It is a good practice to separate HTML and CSS (that is, not write styles inline) :

```css
table { 
     width : 100% 
}

col:nth-child(1){ 
        width : 30% 
}

col:nth-child(2){ 
        width : 10% 
}

td:nth-child(2){ 
       text-align : right 
}
```

```html
<h4>Japan:</h4>
     <table>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
           <td>Value1:</td>
           <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value2:</td>
           <td>500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value3:</td>
           <td>33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value4:</td>
           <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value5:</td>
           <td>123</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     <h4>China:</h4>
              <table>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
           <td>Value1:</td>
           <td>600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value2:</td>
           <td>1100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value3:</td>
           <td>444</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value4:</td>
           <td>1112</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Value5:</td>
           <td>123321</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can reduce code by adding css file. or use this code in your head tag:

```
<style>
table {
    width:100%;
}
td { 
    text-align:right;
}
</style>
```